# Extract Header from ShapeShifter

Tags: roscpp, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to implement something similar to  rospy.anymessage via roscpp. I am using Shapeshifter to extract the data. I only need the Header.stamp (I want to compare received time from the time the topic was published).

I'm running into a wall trying to extract the header stamp. I know rosbag imeplement something like this, but I could only find they use SubscriptionCallbackHelperT, but not how.

How can I extract the Header.stamp from a generic ros topic message?

```
void PerformanceTracker::topicCallback(const ShapeShifter::ConstPtr topicType){
   ros::Time begin = ros::Time::now();
   unsigned char* data = ShapeShifterGetData(topicType);
}

unsigned char* ShapeShifterGetData(const ShapeShifter::ConstPtr message){
  unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[message->size()];
  std::OStream stream(data, message->size());
  message->write(stream);
  return data;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226392/extract-header-from-shapeshifter/) by [solb22](https://answers.ros.org/users/25924/solb22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's easily understandable way that has to drawback of always serializing messages and interpreting the serialized result: [topic_buffer_client](https://github.com/jsk-ros-pkg/jsk_common/blob/master/jsk_topic_tools/src/topic_buffer_client.cpp#L88).

It looks like a more efficient way using [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) seems to be implemented here: [timeextractor.h](https://github.com/NimbRo/nimbro-op-ros/blob/master/src/nimbro_vis/timewarp/include/timewarp/timeextractor.h)
With the template magic it's a bit harder to understand though ;)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [solb22](https://answers.ros.org/users/25924/solb22/) on 2016-02-12**:
Thanks Stefan, I will try both and get back to you. What do you means the drawback of always serializing messages? Are you saying serializing the messages wastes computation time? I can set the received time to before the serialization starts, so it wont affect the measurement of published-received

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-02-12**:
Yes, serialization can take up some CPU time (and it seems the second approach can do it without serialization).

**Comment by [solb22](https://answers.ros.org/users/25924/solb22/) on 2016-02-12**:
Ok thanks. Yes the SFINAE is much less clear. Would I just include that file and user timewarp.extractTime() ? Thank you very much for the help !

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-02-12**:
Might be possible, but you could also copy parts and make your own minimal version of it (You're not really using it for "timewarping" for instance).

**Comment by [solb22](https://answers.ros.org/users/25924/solb22/) on 2016-02-12**:
Yeah, I'm going to port that to C++11

**Comment by [solb22](https://answers.ros.org/users/25924/solb22/) on 2016-02-12**:
One last question. Why in the SFINAE, is it     static yes& test(typename C::_header_type*); ? What does C::_header_type* mean? Type has a data member named _header_type? Does that match the current ros header data member name? And not just plain  C::_header*?